# Finding apps in playstore by link not by publisher name

Tags: android, search, google-play

Is there any way to find my all apps in play store, not by publisher name but with a link so it shows only my own applications?
currently i am using this method.
i search for
pub:Muhammad Asim or something like this for searching my apps.
it shows my applications but it also shows applications of matching publisher names.

[image]

i simply don't want other users apps to show in my search.
is there any way to view only my own applications so if i sent it to other users they can download my applications?

Comment: You can find an app by package name this way: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=my.package.identifier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to go to this link :) https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=Muhammad+Asim

Hope it will help !

Comment: how did you got it? is there any way to get this code?

Comment: On the app list you have posted a screenshot, you will see your name, just below the app's name: this is the link :D